# Is "IBM Watson IoT Platform Local" the same thing as "Bluemix Local"?

Tags: local, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

5725-Z57 SaaS IBM Watson IoT Platform Local
IBM Watson IoT Platform Local delivers rapid access to devices and data
http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=877&letternum=ENUSZP16-0214#etechinfx

So is "IBM Watson IoT Platform Local" the same thing as "Bluemix Local" ?
If so, is this the place I goto for the install requirements -> https://console.au-syd.bluemix.net/docs/local/index.html#localinfra ?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for technical questions only. Please post questions like this about specific Bluemix and Watson offerings on the IBM developerWorks Answers forum, https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different products.

The Watson IoT platform is, essentially, a MQTT broker and related services (MQTT is kind of like a simpler version of HTTP targeted at embedded devices).

Bluemix is IBM's Platform-as-a-Service, offering virtual servers (like Heroku) and access to various APIs.

The "local" part in each just means that you can use each system in your own facility instead at an IBM facility.